# Increment inline style left position

Tags: jquery

I have several elements and each has inline style with "left" value. I need to loop through and increase that LEFT value to space each element 10px apart from each other.

So I tried something like this:

```
$('.myElement').each(function() {
    var lft = lft + 10;
    var pos = $(this).css('left') + lft;
    $(this).css('left', pos + 'px');
});
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to adjust your value in the `.css` method:

```
$('.myElement').each(function() {        
    $(this).css('left', '+=' + 10 );    
});
```

[Click here for an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/sanpopo/kkM9x/)